# Android Maps - how to manage a large number of markers (1 million+)

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Managing a large number of markers for Google Maps in Android is all fine and dandy when you have 20-50K markers.

But how do you manage hundreds of thousands or even millions? What's better - performance wise - storing them in a JSON file locally on the device or retrieving a very large number of markers remotely?

I believe clustering is no huge issue with a very large number of markers - I've tested it with 50k markers and it runs acceptably smooth.

Are there any other performance considerations? Corners I can cut?

Comment: Most likely, you will run out of heap space with "hundreds of thousands or even millions" of model objects. Hence, you will need to come up with some solution that allows you to only have a subset of those model objects in memory at one time.

Comment: MuhammadBabar, I'm not talking about clustering, I'm talking about retrieving and managing a very large number of markers.

CommonsWare, I can partly understand. Could you please go in depth a bit more?

Comment: Fusion Table is the best option in your particular use case. Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15415785/4386486.

Comment: You can implement selective rendering based on some criteria or viewport which the answer discusses about. Basically only render according to relevance and your performance should not be affected adversely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Fusion Maps is highly experimental, and makes your data visible for the public. It also limits the number of markers to 100k.

Google in particular is very strict when dealing with API calls, limiting the number you can do.

So, I've used CartoDB. It has more or less the same feature as the Google Maps stack, but it's open-source.